# Average engagement time always zero, is a tag change needed after migration?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Any ideas, average (page visit) engagement time is always zero in new GA4 after migrated with the old tags to GA4.  What kind of tag change is required to make it work?

The time seems to work with other migrated sites.

This is the migrated tag that is having this issue:

```
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'XX', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
        
         // Load the plugin.
          ga('require', 'linker'); 
          ga('require', 'GTM-XX');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you migrate from Universal Analytics (UA) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4), there are several significant differences in how data is collected, processed, and presented. One of the main differences is the way sessions and engagement metrics are defined and tracked.

In GA4, the "Engagement Time" metric is intended to offer a more accurate representation of user interaction than the old "Average Session Duration" metric in UA. This is because "Engagement Time" counts only when users are actively engaging with the page, such as when they click, scroll, or type.

However, if you're noticing that the average engagement time is always zero for a site after migrating, there might be several potential reasons:

1. **Incomplete Migration**: Simply updating the UA tracking code will not work for GA4. GA4 uses a different type of tracking code (`gtag.js`) as compared to UA (`analytics.js`). Make sure you've added the new GA4 tracking code to your website.
2. **Event Tracking**: GA4 relies heavily on events to calculate engagement. If no additional events beyond the initial page view are tracked, this might result in zero engagement time. Ensure that you have the necessary events set up, such as scroll tracking and link click tracking.
3. **GTM Configuration**: If you're using Google Tag Manager (GTM), ensure that it's properly set up for GA4. The GTM setup for UA and GA4 is different. You might want to ensure that GA4 configuration in GTM is correct.
4. **Double-check Property**: It's a basic step, but sometimes overlooked. Ensure that you're checking the correct property and view in GA4. If you've multiple properties or views, you might be looking at one that doesn't have any data.
5. **Check Filters & Data Streams**: Ensure there are no filters or configurations that are preventing the engagement data from being recorded. Also, double-check the data streams in GA4 to ensure they are correctly set up.
6. **Debugging with Tag Assistant**: Use Google's Tag Assistant to see if there are any issues with the GA tags on your website. This can provide clues about any misconfigurations or errors.
7. **Delay in Data Reporting**: Sometimes, there might be a delay in the reporting of data in GA4. Although real-time data is often available, it's possible there might be a delay in some metrics.

To ensure everything works correctly:

1. Transition to the new `gtag.js` if you haven't already.
2. Implement event tracking relevant to your site's user interactions.
3. Ensure that Google Tag Manager, if used, is set up properly for GA4.

If all configurations seem correct and you're still facing the issue, consider reaching out to Google's support or consulting with a Google Analytics specialist. They might be able to provide a deep dive into your specific setup and identify any issues.

I am sharing some links for better undrestanding:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13486733?hl=en
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Biow-Qkst68
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ot3zfNYNQ

Comment: thanks but Googles automatic migration worked ok for all other sites without changing a tag

Comment: interesting, we needed to change everything :D